# What is the Significance of timestamps with/without time zone in PostgreSQL and when to use them?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, sqldatatypes, timestamp-with-timezone

I need to save a current location of a car in an app which operates only in USA and I'm confused with datatype of psql between `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` and `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. Can the differences be explained ?

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) "*All timezone-aware dates and times are stored internally in UTC. They are converted to local time in the zone specified by the TimeZone configuration parameter before being displayed to the client*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: okay that was useful info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is

- The storage of TIME or TIMESTAMP differs between one WITH TIME ZONE  or WITHOUT TIME ZONE
- With a time zone as part of the value , the value could be local time in the client side
- Without a time zone , value will be UTC Time by default .

So by default it will be saved in UTC , You can convert into specific time zones .